# Execute javascript even when an error occurs on an external page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a javascript file into an external page. And want a specific code to execute after the external page is loaded.

```
window.onload = function() { 
\* execute this code after the page is loaded *\ 
}
```

But the code won't execute if there's an error on the external page I want to execute this code on, like an undefined variable or something like that. Is there a way to let the code ignore the errors and just execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [try catch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try {
   // execute code here
} catch (e) {
  // if an error was thrown, execute this code.
  // e references related error object
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the errors aren't caused by the javascript file, but by the external page.

Comment: @user900973 terribly sorry. maybe you could attach some code to the onerror event of the window? Otherwise if the malformed code breaks execution and yours is not reached, there's no manner of code that you could use to help in that situation.

Comment: Well, I think the code gets broken by the external page. I did some tests and it seems that window.onload can be executed too when window.onerror can be executed.

Comment: Thank you! :) (see post below)

Answer (score 0):

However, there are cases when the `window.onerror` suggestion by Joseph does work! :)
So, my scripts will be loaded in the external page with this code:

```
window.onerror = window.onload = function() { 
\* execute this code after the page is loaded *\ 
}
```